# Dynamically filter Playa field based on children of current selection in another Playa field

Tags: playa

I want to publish a channel entry that enables members to select entries that are related through a Playa relations. For example I have a channel that members will use to create a entry (let's call this a REPORT). In that entry, I'm using Playa so members to select related entries from another channel (let's call this DEPARTMENTS). This all works fined. I can create a REPORT and relate to it specific DEPARTMENTS.

I also have another channel (let's call this EMPLOYEES) that is also Playa related to DEPARTMENTS.

Is it possible through Playa to select specific EMPLOYEES from the DEPARTMENTS selected.

So I'm trying to relate specific EMPLOYEES to my REPORT.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way you are thinking, no.

You can add another Playa field to your Reports channel which lists Employees, but there's no way to have it dynamically filter to only display the employees which are selected in the Departments entry you've selected on the same entry screen.